# If $x = \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{6}$ is a root of $x^4 + ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$, where $a, b, c$ and $d$ are integers, what is $|a + b + c + d|$?

Tags: polynomials, contest-math, absolute-value, irrational-numbers

From the [Pre-Regional Mathematics Olympiad, 2019](https://www.mtai.org.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/PRMO-2019-Question-Paper-August-25.pdf):

> If $x = \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{6}$ is a root of $x^4 + ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$, where $a, b, c$ and $d$ are integers, what is $|a + b + c + d|$?

I have provided one answer below, and would be interested in alternative solutions.

Comment: Please review [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|126.8286)

Comment: @amWhy I asked this question with the intent of answering it myself. In such a case, should I detail/explain my attempts to solve my question, and if so, how?

Comment: You should instead include your working and attempt in your question.

Comment: You need to provide more context than a mere problem statement.  You can also explain that you are posting the question with the intent of answering it.  But we prefer genuine questions.  Adding more background to the question, informing users that you have found and answer, and Adding something like, "I'd be interested in seeing alternative solutions, different from the one I present below" is also advised.

Comment: @amWhy Thank you, answering questions myself is something I tend to do a lot as a way to save interesting/difficult problems. I have edited my question.

Comment: After your edit, I reversed my downvote of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can rewrite $x =\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt6$ as
$$\begin{aligned}(x-\sqrt2)^2 &= (\sqrt2 + \sqrt6)^2\\
x^2 - 2\sqrt2x+2 &= 9 + 6\sqrt2\\
x^2-7&=2\sqrt2\space(x+3)\end{aligned}$$
On squaring both sides of the equation,
$$x^4-22x^2-48x-23=0$$
Therefore, $a = 0, b = -22, c = -48, d = -23$, implying $|a+b+c+d| = 93$

Comment: You probably mean $(x-\sqrt 2)^2=(\sqrt 3+\sqrt 6)^2$?

Comment: You missed one step. You need to prove that the minimal polynomial of that number has degree $4$.

Comment: Looks like the right idea.  A couple small mistakes.  First, as kingW3 noted.  Also, $1-22-48-23=-92$.  The rest looks good.

Comment: @Daniel Schepler Yes.

Comment: @kingW3 Yes, thank you. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The only part missing in the existing answer is the fact that the minimal polynomial of $a=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{6}$ has degree $4$, i.e. the degree of the extension $|\Bbb{Q}[a]:\Bbb{Q}|$ is $4$. Since $a$ is a root of an integer  polynomial of degree $4$, the degree of the extension is $1, 2$ or $4$. It cannot be $1$ since $a$ is not rational. If the degree is $2$ then for some rational $p,q$ you have $a^2+pa+q=0$ or $11+2(\sqrt{6}+2\sqrt{3}+3\sqrt{2})+pa+q=0$. But that is impossible. So, indeed, the degree is $4$.

Another way to prove it is to consider homomorphisms from $\Bbb{Q}[a]$ to $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}]$ (which has degree $4$). There are $4$ of those.

Comment: Although this is correct, it cannot be the intended answer as nobody knows what is "minimal polynomial" or "degree of the extension" in a math olympiad.

Comment: When I participated in math olympiads I knew these things and many other participants knew this too. In any case I do not know how else this can be proved. If you know post your answer.

Comment: By "nobody knows" I mean it is not considered as standard technique required for solving problems. I think one approach is to show that $a$ cannot be a root of a polynomial of degree $3$. Or perhaps show directly that the polynomial $x^4-22x^2-48x-23=0$ is irreducible.

Comment: Then you will have to find $a^3$ and argue that if $a$ is a root of two monic polynomials of degree 4 then it is a root of a polynomial of degree 3 or 2 or 1.

Comment: You seem to think that the notion of irreducible polynomial is "known". And all the other properties of polynomials are also "known" except the basic field theory.

Comment: Of course polynomials are frequently used in math olympiad. But NEVER field theory. I was just guessing what could be the intended answer. But looking at their other problems, I think there is even no intended "proof" of what you are proving, as "the correction is done by machines through scanning".

Comment: That is correct: they did not need proofs. But the OP wanted a proof  and produced most of it. I just added a missed part.

Answer (score 0):

Using a bit of Galois theory: first, note that the intermediate fields between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$ are $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$, and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6})$, none of which contains $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{6}$.  Therefore, $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{6}$ is a primitive generator of the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$ of $\mathbb{Q}$, so the degree of its minimal polynomial is $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}) : \mathbb{Q}] = 4$.

Now, also note that if the minimal polynomial is $p(x) = x^4 + ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$, then $a + b + c + d = p(1) - 1$.  On the other hand, we also know that $p(x) = \prod_{\sigma \in G} (x - \sigma(\alpha))$ where $G = \operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}) / \mathbb{Q})$ and $\alpha = \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{6}$.  Therefore, $p(1) = N^{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})}_{\mathbb{Q}}(1 - \alpha)$.

But also,
$$
N^{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})}_{\mathbb{Q}} (1 - \alpha) = N^{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})}_{\mathbb{Q}} N^{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})} [(1 - \sqrt{2}) - (1 + \sqrt{2}) \sqrt{3}] = \\
N^{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})}_{\mathbb{Q}} [(1 - \sqrt{2})^2 - 3 (1 + \sqrt{2})^2] = N^{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})}_{\mathbb{Q}} (-6 - 8 \sqrt{2}) = 6^2 - 2 \cdot 8^2 = -92.
$$
Thus, $a + b + c + d = -93$, and $|a + b + c + d| = 93$.